# How can I add the widget scale on my tkinter app?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a code in Python and I want to add a widget scale. Here is my code :

```
import Tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

app = tk.Tk()
app.wm_title("Graphe Matplotlib dans Tkinter")

fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=96)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10), [5, 4, 2, 6, 9, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3])

graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=app)
canvas = graph.get_tk_widget()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

app.mainloop()
```

And the widget scale is like this :

```
value = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale(window, variable=value)
scale.pack()
```

I want to put at the right of the window the widget scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want to achieve but If you want to add a Scale widget sticked to the east side of your plot, add the lines below before your `app.mainloop()`:

```
value = tk.DoubleVar()
scale = tk.Scale(app, variable=value, orient="vertical")
scale.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="wens")
```